# Expire user session in passport.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, session, passport.js

I have used passport-local strategy and after authentication, I have store authenticated user data in localstorage. I can clear it when logout, but how I can expire the user session?

I am using session and not JWT token.

Any idea of how to implement a session expiry?

My frontend is react.js

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean to destroy the session in the server side, the session object has a destroy() function. By calling that function you can destroy the session data.

Comment: Thanks but not just that. I want to notify it for the client-side as well

Comment: How are you storing the session details in the client side? cookies?

Comment: @ Shree Charan At the moment in local storage But i am thinking to move it to cookies